# Finding the PDF of a product of two r.v.s

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X,Y \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ be independent of each other. Find the PDF of $V:= XY$.

This is was I did
$$\mathbb{P}(V \leq v) = \mathbb{P}(YX \leq v) = \mathbb{P}\left(Y\leq \frac v X \right) \\ = \int_0^{v/x} 1 \, dy = \frac v x.$$
I'm not sure if this is right since I can't think of the restrictions and also there involves an $x$ term in the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v \in (0,1)$,

\begin{align}
P( Y \le \frac{v}{X})&= \int_0^1 P(Y \le \frac{v}{x})\, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \min\left( 1, \frac{v}{x}\right)\, dx \\
&= \int_0^v \, dx + \int_v^1  \frac{v}{x}\, dx \\
&= v-v\log v \\
\end{align}

Differentiate it to obtain the pdf.

Edit:

$$f_V(v) = \begin{cases} -\log v &, v \in (0,1) \\ 0 & \text{, otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Comment: How did you get the first equality (the upper bound being $1$)?

Comment: I consider every single value that $x$ can possibly take. there is actually an invisble $f_X(x)$ inside the integral.

Comment: Oh is it actually $\int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(Y\leq v/X | X=x) f_X(x) dx$?

Comment: yes, you get it.

Comment: Thank you, and one last Q: why does $P(Y\leq v/x) = min(1,v/x)$? I thought you'd need to do another integral using the joint distribution

Comment: $Y$ is a uniform distribution, we know the CDF of the uniform distribution if $y$ is positive is $F_Y(y) = \min(y,1)$.

Comment: In the first step actually, we looked at $P(Y\leq v/x) = F_Y(v/x)$.  
This looks like I'm finding the probability cumulation of $Y$ aren't I?

Comment: Yup, but $X$ is a random variable there.

Comment: Hmm, so in the end the answer is $F_Y(v/x) = v-v log(v)$ and diff. wrt. $v$, i get $f_Y(v/x) \frac{1}{x} = -log(v)$ which seems really confusing

Comment: $-\log v$ is the correct solution.

Comment: What should I be differentiating with respect by? Since when I differentiate wrt $v$, I get the extra factor of $x$ giving $-xlog(v)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74964/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-mr-bromwich-i).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(XY\le v) = \operatorname E(\Pr(XY\le v \mid X)) = \operatorname E\left( \Pr \left( Y \le \frac v X \,\middle|\, X \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E \left.\begin{cases} \dfrac v X & \text{if } \dfrac v X <1 \\[12pt] 1 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases} \right\} = \int_v^1 \frac v x \cdot 1 \, dx + \int_0^v 1 \,dx = v(1-\log_e v).
\end{align}